# ASP.NET Core sessions lost in Docker swarm

Tags: docker, asp.net-core

I'm converting my ASP.NET Core app to run inside a Docker stack. I currently have it configured to use 5 replicated containers for the web layer, all connecting to one MySQL container. The site seems to be working fine aside from the fact that I keep getting logged out of the site every few pages, presumably because I'm hitting a different worker node than the one I logged in to. I'm having troubles finding online resources for how to use the database to persist login sessions, because it seems they're being persisted in-memory instead.

Am I right in my diagnosis of why this is happening? If so, what's the solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up having to revisit this problem again and was disappointed that there were no answers, but I ended up solving the problem. I had already tried using `Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Redis` to set up a Redis-based distributed cache:

```
// Persist session to distributed cache
services.AddDistributedRedisCache(options => {
    options.Configuration = this.Configuration.GetConnectionString("Redis");
    options.InstanceName  = "RedisCache";
});
```

However, the sessions were still being lost whenever the client would bounce between nodes. I eventually discovered that even though the sessions were being persisted to Redis, the data protection keys used to encrypt the session tokens were being stored in-memory, meaning they were lost any time a container would update. I solved this with `Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.Redis`. Sadly there is no "release" version of this package, but there is a prerelease version: `Install-Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.Redis -Version 2.2.0-preview2-35157`

I then set it up as such:

```
var redisConnection = this.Configuration.GetConnectionString("Redis");
var redis = ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect(redisConnection);

// Persist data protection keys to distributed cache
services.AddDataProtection()
        .PersistKeysToRedis(redis, "DataProtection-Keys");

// Persist session to distributed cache
services.AddDistributedRedisCache(options => {
    options.Configuration = redisConnection;
    options.InstanceName  = "RedisCache";
});
```

This last step was **absolutely key** for the cross-server sessions to work correctly. Hopefully this helps someone else!